# AxisError in a catch block returning wrong status code 200

Tags: typescript, axios

Making a POST api call to Salesforece, not been able to return the correct status code to the client, it is returning the correct error message but wrong status code, should be 400 but is returning 200

Here is the request that calls the `handleCreateBusinessContactCase` func.

```
@Post('case/businessContact')
  public async handleCreateBusinessContactCase(
    @Body() requestBody: ContactRequest,
    @Request() request: koa.Request,
    @Header('X-Correlation-Id') correlationId?: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const logCtx = LogContext.getLogContext(request.ctx, 'handleCreateBusinessContactCase');
    const repsone = await createBusinessContactCase(logCtx, requestBody);
    return Promise.resolve(repsone);
  }

.....
return axios({
    url,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.authentication}`,
    },
    data: jsonData,
    timeout: 10000
  }).then((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
    /*if (response.status === 401) {
      log.debug(`SaleForce refused token, clear the token and try once more, status code: ${response.status}`);
    }*/
    return response.data
  }).catch((error: AxiosError) => {
    console.log(error.response?.data);  
    console.log(error.response?.status);  
    console.log(error.response?.headers); 
    return error.response?.data
  });
```

The output from the `console.log` lines is as expected, but in the swagger UI I get the correct message but the status code is 200, should be 400!

Here is the log output

```
[
  {
    message: "Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 0120Y000000VLBKQA4",
    errorCode: 'INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY',
    fields: [ 'RecordTypeId' ]
  }
]
400
{
  date: 'Sun, 10 Oct 2021 23:31:46 GMT',
  'set-cookie': [
    'CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; domain=icelandair--test.my.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 10-Oct-2022 23:31:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000',
    'LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; domain=my.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 10-Oct-2022 23:31:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000',
    'BrowserId=PDDStioiEeyHw1UM8hQSng; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 10-Oct-2022 23:31:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000'
  ],
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-robots-tag': 'none',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private',
  'sforce-limit-info': 'api-usage=17224/5000000',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

Comment: Presumably there's some other code that represents your API that calls this Axios function. How does that code handle the response? FYI, your `catch` transforms the rejected promise into a successful one.

Comment: I've added the missing code.

Comment: @Phil how do I make the error trickle all the up to the client, I've tried to throw the error, but that did not give me the correct message nor status code, I got `Code: 500`and message `Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: So as mentioned, you've turned your rejected Axios promise into a resolved one which your controller interprets as successful. You don't seem to be doing anything useful with your `catch` so I'd just omit it. Have you seen this part of the Koa documentation? https://koajs.com/#response

Comment: this worked, removing the `return Promise.resolve(repsone)` and just return the obj. from the handler `return createBusinessContactCase(logCtx, requestBody);` then I just created my return obj. like this in the handler `throw { message: error.response?.data, status: error.response?.status };` thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer below

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to modify first the Controller to not always resolve the promise

```
@Post('case/businessContact')
  public async handleCreateBusinessContactCase(
    @Body() requestBody: ContactRequest,
    @Request() request: koa.Request,
    @Header('X-Correlation-Id') correlationId?: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const logCtx = LogContext.getLogContext(request.ctx, 'handleCreateBusinessContactCase');
    return createBusinessContactCase(logCtx, requestBody);
  }
```

Then I could format the return obj. as I like from the handler like this

```
export  const createBusinessContactCase() = async(): Promise<anty> {
return axios({
    url,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.authentication}`,
    },
    data: jsonData,
    timeout: 10000
  }).then((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
    /*if (response.status === 401) {
      log.debug(`SaleForce refused token, clear the token and try once more, status code: ${response.status}`);
    }*/
    return response.data
  }).catch((error: AxiosError) => {
    throw { message: error.response?.data, status: error.response?.status };
  });
};
}
```